# Opening Excel - Call rejected by Callee

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to open Excel with Com addins via PowerShell and keep getting a "Call was rejected by callee" error, please see code below. Any thoughts?

```
$a = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$a.Visible = $True
```

```
Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001
(RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))
At line:2 char:1
+ $a.Visible = $True
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Comment: Have you seen [How to: Fix 'Application is Busy' and 'Call was Rejected By Callee' Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I saw that but I can't make sense of it. Running that script didn't work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[This reference](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/9db8e065-bed4-4944-991f-058639b6de48) is more appropriate for PowerShell users.  The code attaches message filters to the current thread, which incidentally means that powershell has to be run in [STA mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff629472.aspx) (the default for powershell 3.0+).

For some messaging and a small pause between re-calls to excel, I added this line to the list of `using` declarations:

```cs
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using System.Threading;              // <- added this line
```

and I added these lines to the re-try handler:

```cs
if (dwRejectType == 2) 
// flag = SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER. 
{
    // Retry the thread call immediately if return >=0 &  
    // <100. 
    string wait_message = "Wait for Excel RPC channel";   // <- added this line
    Console.WriteLine(wait_message);                      // <- added this line
    Thread.Sleep(100);                                    // <- added this line
    return 99;
}
```

In addition, if a user happens to hit the keyboard or click on a visible application, Excel will throw `RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED` continuously, unless you call this before your set your application instance to visible.

```sh
$Application.Interactive = $false
```

After sourcing the referenced script, your code becomes:

```sh
$a = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
AddMessageFilterClass 
$Application.Interactive = $false
$a.Visible = $True
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI this also seems to occur when `Visible` is `$false`, for example:

`New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application -Property @{Visible = $false}`

Also, in my case it only threw the error when launched via WinRM; if I executed the script on the host machine, it worked perfectly fine.